# How to normally start process using wxWidgets

Tags: shell, process, wxwidgets

According official manuals, i tested this code:

```
wxProcess * proc = wxProcess::Open("C:\\windows\\notepad.exe");
```

but this code doesn't work properly, i see working notepad process in System Manager, but there is no notepad windows and etc. Also if i start console application - no text neither in new console window nor in mine.

How to fix that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need neither IO redirection nor process termination notification, the simplest way to launch a process is to use [wxExecute](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__procctrl.html#ga8116ca17aec4eea74b848f1544805960) with `wxEXEC_ASYNC` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Provided code works fine for me with any other application, e.g. `calc`.

```
wxProcess * process = wxProcess::Open(wxT("calc"));
wxLogDebug(wxT("Process: %s"), process != NULL ? wxT("OK") : wxT("Error"));
```

Shows OK and calc window appears.